# Using Laravel database migrations and seeds without Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel application which has the database set up using migrations. We have decided to move to Phalcon for a number of reasons, and due to this, onboarding new members of staff poses a few problems when it comes to migrations and seeding. Since we don't have a database already for the new member of staff, we need to create a database for them with seed data.

We could just create a SQL file with the prepared database and seed data already filled, however I was wondering if and how possible it would be to utilise Laravel's migrations in a non-Laravel application.

Migrations seem like one thing which should be relatively easy to use without Laravel, however there is very little information about doing this or even if it is possible.

Does anybody have any experience with this? What approach did you take?

Comment: You need to use `Illuminate\database`, [this](https://siipo.la/blog/how-to-use-eloquent-orm-migrations-outside-laravel) might help you.

Comment: That's a good start, the problem I see is the migration files already exist. That uses Phinx to handle the migrations so if anything has already been migrated, it'll not know the classes if I copy them over. I'll have a play around and see how far I get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one major reason why running Laravel migrations without the framework is difficult: **facades**.

Using the `Schema` facade pretty much locks you into the framework at that point. Unless you want to go through the trouble of writing your own `\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application` implementation, and bootstrap the facades yourself.

If you don't, you already need to do the work to replace facade usage in your migrations. Might as well continue replacing them entirely with Phinx migrations at that point.

It's definitely possible to keep your Laravel migrations as-is. But is it worth it? Especially if you'd prefer to move to Phinx entirely in the future.

Also consider: if a lot of your Laravel migrations are now stale and don't represent the current database structure, why keep them?

Comment: You've raised a lot of good points, thank you. I think that the stale migrations issue is a good one to bring up, since I could just generate Phinx migrations using the current database schema rather than go up and down through the whole migration stack. There's not going to be a need to traverse that far back since the whole application is being re-written, but it still has the problem of not knowing what migrations to run, unless I manually add them to the Phinx log on the live server. That's a different question entirely, however!

Comment: Your initial Phinx migration can check if tables already exist before creating them. While it will be a pretty large first migration, you don't need to worry about what's in the DB already. Or, your first migration might be to manipulate the existing `migrations` table, if you want to repurpose it.

Answer (score 1):

I always use Phinx outside of Laravel to accomplish this. There docs are pretty solid on getting going.

http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html

Comment: We are using Phinx migrations already, however we have a number of migrations already written in Laravel which we need to run. The problem is running migrations that already exist in Laravel outside of that project, either by copying the files over and running the migrator, or by using the guide in the comment by The Alpha to allow Phinx to read the migrations in some way.